# Flink Table API : AppendStreamTableSink doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node GroupAggregate

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to generate aggregates on a Streaming Source and when i try to run the Table API queries i am getting the following Error.

AppendStreamTableSink doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node GroupAggregate

I am consuming the data from a Kafka Topic. Here is the Unit Test i am to mimic that behavior.

```
    msg_type_1,Site_1,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_2,Site_1,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_1,Site_2,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_1,Site_3,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_1,Site_4,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_1,Site_5,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_1,Site_1,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_2,Site_1,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_3,Site_2,09/10/2020,00:00:00.037
msg_type_4,Site_1,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
msg_type_1,Site_3,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
msg_type_2,Site_1,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
msg_type_3,Site_4,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
msg_type_4,Site_1,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
msg_type_1,Site_4,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
msg_type_2,Site_5,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
msg_type_4,Site_5,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
msg_type_6,Site_5,09/10/2020,00:10:00.037
```

And here is the Unit Test i have for the aggregation.

```
@Test
    public void loadSampleMessageFile() {
        System.out.println(".loadSampleMessageFile() : ");
        try {
            String[] args = {};
            StreamExecutionEnvironment streamingExecutionEnv = null;
            streamingExecutionEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

            streamingExecutionEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);

            //streamingExecutionEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

            ExecutionConfig config = streamingExecutionEnv.getConfig();
            final ParameterTool paramTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
            for (int index = 0; index < args.length; index++) {
                logger.info("Argument =" + index + " Value" + args[index]);
            }
            streamingExecutionEnv.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(paramTool);

            StreamTableEnvironment streamTableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(streamingExecutionEnv);

            SingleOutputStreamOperator<SampleMessage> dataStreamSource = streamingExecutionEnv
                    .readTextFile("C:\\temp\\sample_data.txt")
                    .map(new MapFunction<String, SampleMessage>() {
                        @Override
                        public SampleMessage map(String value) throws Exception {
                            return sampleMessageParser.parseMessage(value, null);
                        }
                    });

            streamTableEnv.createTemporaryView("messages", dataStreamSource);

            Table messagesTable = streamTableEnv.fromDataStream(dataStreamSource);

            System.out.println("No.of Columns in Table =" + messagesTable.getSchema().getFieldCount());
            logger.info("No.of Columns in Table =" + messagesTable.getSchema().getFieldCount());

            for (int index = 0; index < messagesTable.getSchema().getFieldNames().length; index++) {
                System.out.println("Field Name [" + index + "] = " + messagesTable.getSchema().getFieldNames()[index]);
            }

            TableResult distinctSiteResult = messagesTable.distinct().select($("site")).execute();

            CloseableIterator distinctSiteResultIter = distinctSiteResult.collect();
            int counter = 0;
            List<String> sites = new ArrayList<>();
            while (distinctSiteResultIter.hasNext()) {
                sites.add((String) distinctSiteResultIter.next());
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Total No.of Distinct Sites =" + counter);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the support classes.

```
public class SampleMessage implements Serializable {

    private String msgType;

    private String site;

    private Long timestamp;

    public String getMsgType() {
        return msgType;
    }

    public void setMsgType(String msgType) {
        this.msgType = msgType;
    }

    public String getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.append("SampleMessage[");
        str.append(" msgType=");
        str.append(msgType);
        str.append(" site=");
        str.append(site);
        str.append(" timestamp=");
        str.append(timestamp);
        str.append(" ]");
        return str.toString();
    }
}
```

And here is the error i am getting.

```
.loadSampleMessageFile() : 
No.of Columns in Table =3
Field Name [0] = msgType
Field Name [1] = site
Field Name [2] = timestamp
org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: AppendStreamTableSink doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node GroupAggregate(groupBy=[msgType, site, timestamp], select=[msgType, site, timestamp])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm the version of flink.
The result of distinct will change continuously. The downstream should be RetractStreamTableSink.

The error shows that this version of flink collect is not supported upsert

The latest version of Flink collect already supports upsert
[image]